# 301 Redirect in htaccess to remove URL Parameter? And redirect to original URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have following pattern of URLs in some of my WordPress site
abc.com/xolo-lt900-price-in-india.html? m=1
and
abc.com/xolo-lt900-price-in-india.html? m=0

I want to remove part which is after parameter value and 301 redirect it to main/original URL.
So,

bc.com/xolo-lt900-price-in-india.html?m=1

Shall 301 redirect to

abc.comprice4india.co.in/xolo-lt900-price-in-india.html

And in same way

abc.com/xolo-lt900-price-in-india.html? m=0

Shall 301 redirect to

abc.com/xolo-lt900-price-in-india.html

I have the following code but its not working.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanksfully the old code from @Anubhava is working now..

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=[01]$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: The `NC` flag does not make any sens in there ...